# Python buf.find('***identified***') >= 0: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to rewrite the [following Python 2 code](https://github.com/lanquarden/pyScrcClient) to Python 3. Inside the repository, there is a `pyclient.py` file. I changed it to the following

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
Created on Apr 4, 2012

@author: lanquarden
'''
import sys
import argparse
import socket
import driver

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass

# Configure the argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Python client to connect to the TORCS SCRC server.')

parser.add_argument('--host', action='store', dest='host_ip', default='localhost',
                    help='Host IP address (default: localhost)')
parser.add_argument('--port', action='store', type=int, dest='host_port', default=3001,
                    help='Host port number (default: 3001)')
parser.add_argument('--id', action='store', dest='id', default='SCR',
                    help='Bot ID (default: SCR)')
parser.add_argument('--maxEpisodes', action='store', dest='max_episodes', type=int, default=1,
                    help='Maximum number of learning episodes (default: 1)')
parser.add_argument('--maxSteps', action='store', dest='max_steps', type=int, default=0,
                    help='Maximum number of steps (default: 0)')
parser.add_argument('--track', action='store', dest='track', default=None,
                    help='Name of the track')
parser.add_argument('--stage', action='store', dest='stage', type=int, default=3,
                    help='Stage (0 - Warm-Up, 1 - Qualifying, 2 - Race, 3 - Unknown)')

arguments = parser.parse_args()

# Print summary
print('Connecting to server host ip:', arguments.host_ip, '@ port:', arguments.host_port)
print('Bot ID:', arguments.id)
print('Maximum episodes:', arguments.max_episodes)
print('Maximum steps:', arguments.max_steps)
print('Track:', arguments.track)
print('Stage:', arguments.stage)
print('*********************************************')

try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
except socket.error as msg:
    print('Could not make a socket.')
    sys.exit(-1)

# one second timeout
sock.settimeout(1.0)

shutdownClient = False
curEpisode = 0

verbose = False

d = driver.Driver(arguments.stage)

while not shutdownClient:
    while True:
        print('Sending id to server: ', arguments.id)
        buf = arguments.id + d.init()
        print('Sending init string to server:', buf)

        try:
            sock.sendto(buf.encode(), (arguments.host_ip, arguments.host_port))
        except socket.error as msg:
            print('Failed to send data...Exiting...')
            sys.exit(-1)

        try:
            buf, addr = sock.recvfrom(1000)
        except socket.error as msg:
            print('didn\'t get response from server...')

        if buf.find('***identified***') >= 0:
            print('Received: ', buf)
            break

    currentStep = 0

    while True:
        # wait for an answer from server
        buf = None
        try:
            buf, addr = sock.recvfrom(1000)
        except socket.error as msg:
            print('didn\'t get response from server...')

        if verbose:
            print('Received: ', buf)

        if buf != None and buf.find('***shutdown***') >= 0:
            d.onShutDown()
            shutdownClient = True
            print('Client Shutdown')
            break

        if buf != None and buf.find('***restart***') >= 0:
            d.onRestart()
            print('Client Restart')
            break

        currentStep += 1
        if currentStep != arguments.max_steps:
            if buf != None:
                buf = d.drive(buf)
        else:
            buf = '(meta 1)'

        if verbose:
            print('Sending: ', buf)

        if buf != None:
            try:
                sock.sendto(buf.encode(), (arguments.host_ip, arguments.host_port))
            except socket.error as msg:
                print('Failed to send data...Exiting...')
                sys.exit(-1)

    curEpisode += 1

    if curEpisode == arguments.max_episodes:
        shutdownClient = True


sock.close()
```

I also changed the `msgParser.py`

```
'''
Created on Apr 5, 2012

@author: lanquarden
'''

class MsgParser(object):
    '''
    A parser for received UDP messages and building UDP messages
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        '''Constructor'''

    def parse(self, str_sensors):
        '''Return a dictionary with tags and values from the UDP message'''
        sensors = {}

        b_open = str_sensors.find('(')

        while b_open >= 0:
            b_close = str_sensors.find(')', b_open)
            if b_close >= 0:
                substr = str_sensors[b_open + 1: b_close]
                items = substr.split()
                if len(items) < 2:
                    print('Problem parsing substring: ', substr)
                else:
                    value = []
                    for i in range(1,len(items)):
                        value.append(items[i])
                    sensors[items[0]] = value
                b_open = str_sensors.find('(', b_close)
            else:
                print('Problem parsing sensor string: "', str_sensors)
                return None

        return sensors

    def stringify(self, dictionary):
        '''Build an UDP message from a dictionary'''
        msg = ''

        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            if value != None and value[0] != None:
                msg += '(' + key
                for val in value:
                    msg += ' ' + str(val)
                msg += ')'

        return msg
```

> **Question:** But when I start TORCS and want to run the module `pyclient.py` I get
>   the following error `buf.find('***identified***') >= 0: TypeError: a
>   bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. I know my code is not a
>   minimal working example but I don't know how to abstract the problem
>   such that I can reproduce the error. I already tried `buf.find('***identified***').encode()` but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: try `buf.find(bytes('***identified***', 'utf-8'))`

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez Thank you for the hint! I got rid of all the errors. Now another error appeared.